# Infer value type by key in array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript

For simplicity I have array of objects with `value` property which can take on different types. I need to infer proper value type by key.

```js
type FormField<TModel> = {
    [K in keyof TModel]: {
        name: K;
        value: TModel[K];
    };
}[keyof TModel];

type FormOptions<TModel> = {
    fields: FormField<TModel>[];
};

export const form = <TModel>(options: FormOptions<TModel>) => {
    return options.fields; // for simplicity only return fields
};
```

then

```js
type FormModel = {
    fullName: string;
    email: string;
    purposes: string[];
    justification: string;
};

const [fullName, email, purposes, justification] = form<FormModel>({
    fields: [
        { name: 'fullName', value: ''},
        { name: 'email', value: ''},
        { name: 'purposes', value: []},
        { name: 'justification', value: ''},
    ],
});

const fn = fullName.value // should be type string but is type string | string[]
```

Thanks to `FormField` type I cannot paste wrong type to value (e.g. empty string into purposes value), but when I return fields, each value in object property is typed as `string | string[]` instead of single type `string[]` or just `string`

Comment: Icky solution that I dislike since `never[]` is inferred instead of `string[]`, but I believe that if you want this sort of API, you need to use currying in some way: https://tsplay.dev/WYRxQw

Comment: If you want the compiler to keep track of the particular order and literal names of the `fields` property then you need to be generic in that type in some way, but the language doesn't support partial type argument inference (see [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242)) so you'd need to work around that; the most common workaround is currying, as shown [in this Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WylZ2m).  Does that fully address the question? If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I don't know why but the solution does not work in my IDE. WebStorm, TS 4.9.4
https://ctrlv.link/Qart

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately a screenshot isn't really anything I can use to help. If you can provide a [mre] of your issue I might be able to do something, but unless the question is explicitly about your particular IDE then it's out of scope. Do you agree that the solution in the playground link above actually addresses the question as asked fully and isn't missing something? If so I'll write up the answer. How would you like me to  proceed here?

Comment: Hello, I finally solved my problem. I used TypeScript recursion. I provide solution. Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

I used TypeScript recursion like this. I provide solution of my full case.

```
type MapFormFields<TModel, TFields extends readonly FormField<TModel, unknown>[]> = TFields extends readonly [
    infer THead,
    ...unknown[],
]
    ? THead extends FormField<TModel, unknown>
        ? [
                Readable<Field<TModel[THead['name']]> & CustomField<TModel[THead['name']]>>,
                ...(TFields extends readonly [unknown, ...infer TTail]
                    ? TTail extends readonly FormField<TModel, unknown>[]
                        ? MapFormFields<TModel, TTail>
                        : never
                    : []),
          ]
        : never
    : [];
```